# Sql table not formatted correctly

Tags: mysql, sql, formatting

I am using the normal INSERT sql statement, but for some reason when I insert code, It comes up as this. Here is my code:

```
$sql="insert into comments (username, comment) values ('$name','$comment')";
mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

My SQL table:

[image: my broken sql table]

Comment: `$comment` has carriage return characters in it.

Comment: the table format in MYSQL is relative to the size of your window

Comment: whats a carriage return? @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's output formatting doesn't work well when there are control characters in a string. It expects each character in the string to take one horizontal space in the output, but newlines go to the beginning of the line.

You can show the newlines as escape sequences with:

```
SELECT username, REPLACE(comment, '\n', '\\n') AS comment, id
FROM comments;
```

It's also possible that there are carriage returns, which go to the beginning of the current line, if the input came from Windows. You can replace those as well with:

```
SELECT username, REPLACE(REPLACE(comment, '\n', '\\n'), '\r', '\\r') AS comment, id
FROM comments;
```

Answer (score 0):

You only must use mysqli_real_escape_string() to escape all characters.

```
$sql="insert into comments (username, comment) values ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($name)."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($comment)."')";
mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

**OR**

```
$name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($name);
$comment = $mysqli->real_escape_string($comment);

$sql="insert into comments (username, comment) values ('$name','$comment')";
mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

Manual : http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-escape-string.php